# Cannot resolve keyword 'is_active' into field?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-allauth

I have the Django `allauth` package included into my project. I am trying to create a custom view of the reset password page with also a custom form. Here's what I have:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^password/reset/$', views.ResetPasswordView.as_view(), name='password-reset'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class ResetPasswordView(PasswordResetView):
    template_name = 'account/password-reset.html'
    form_class = ResetPasswordForm
```

**forms.py**

```
class ResetPasswordForm(PasswordResetForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].label = ""
        self.fields['email'].widget = forms.EmailInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Email Address"})
```

However, for some reason when I enter an email address to reset a password, I get the following error:

> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     41.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in view
>     68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in dispatch
>     88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py" in
>   post
>     102.             response = self.form_valid(form)
>
> File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py" in
>   form_valid
>     639.         form.save(self.request)
>
> File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py"
>   in save
>     269.         for user in self.get_users(email):
>
> File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py"
>   in get_users
>     254.             'is_active': True,
>
> File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in
>   manager_method
>     85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in
>   filter
>     784.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in
>   _filter_or_exclude
>     802.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
>
> File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py"
>   in add_q
>     1250.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
>
> File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py"
>   in _add_q
>     1276.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
>
> File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py"
>   in build_filter
>     1154.         lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
>
> File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py"
>   in solve_lookup_type
>     1034.         _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
>
> File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py"
>   in names_to_path
>     1352.                                      "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
>
> Exception Type: FieldError at /password/reset/ Exception Value: Cannot
>   resolve keyword 'is_active' into field. Choices are: Profile,
>   Profile_id, active, admin, date_joined, email, emailaddress,
>   favorites_count, follower_count, followers, following_count, id,
>   last_login, logentry, password, points_count, questions_count,
>   socialaccount, staff, targets, username

When I remove the form_class from the view and use the default form, it works correctly. Why is it not working when I add the custom form?

Comment: Nowhere do you show something with `is_active`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the is_active is a method in the User model to check whether or not the user is active. `active` is a boolean field in User. Other than that, I don't use is_active anywhere

Comment: Did you by any change changed the `User` model with a model that uses `active` instead of `is_active`?

Comment: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html scroll to the acocunt forms header. Does this section help you?

Comment: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html

Comment: @ritlew Yes, I've added that and for some reason it still gives me the same error

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No I didn't touch it. It's weird that when removing the custom form it starts working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The reason why it was producing this type of error is because I was inheriting from Auth and not Allauth for forms.

**forms.py**

```
class ResetPasswordForm(PasswordResetForm):
```

`PasswordResetForm` is from Auth and not Allauth. Allauth's class name is called: `ResetPasswordForm` after knowing this, my result was this:

```
class PasswordResetForm(ResetPasswordForm):
```

It works correctly now and does not give me that error.